# How to fill in keys of nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a nested dictionary whose values are all 0.
e.g.

```
dic = {0:{'year': 0, 'drive': 0, 'local': 0,},
       1:{'day': 0, 'element': 0, 'party': 0},
       2:{'carry': 0}}
```

I also have a list of words:

```
wordlist = ['light', 'day', 'year', 'day', 'party', 'care', 'local']
```

I want to check for each word in the wordlist if it appears in the dictionary, and if it does, append the relative key by 1.

So for the above example I want the following output:

```
dic = {0:{'year': 1, 'drive': 0, 'local': 1,},
       1:{'day': 2, 'element': 0, 'party': 1},
       2:{'carry': 0}}
```

Comment: There is no necessity for using nested dictionaries in this case

Comment: If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here with your code.

Comment: I think collections.defaultdict might be a part of your solution, but when you say the keys are all 0, I think you mean the values?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can use a nested `for` loop:

```
dic = {0:{'year': 0, 'drive': 0, 'local': 0,},
       1:{'day': 0, 'element': 0, 'party': 0},
       2:{'carry': 0}}

wordlist = ['light', 'day', 'year', 'day', 'party', 'care', 'local']

for word in wordlist:
    for index in dic:
        if word in dic[index]:
            dic[index][word] += 1
```

Output:

```
{0: {'year': 1, 'drive': 0, 'local': 1}, 1: {'day': 2, 'element': 0, 'party': 1}, 2: {'carry': 0}}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is simple to store into dict after counting.

```py
dic = {0:{'year': 0, 'drive': 0, 'local': 0,},
       1:{'day': 0, 'element': 0, 'party': 0},
       2:{'carry': 0}}

wordlist = ['light', 'day', 'year', 'day', 'party', 'care', 'local']

keys=[k for v in dic.values() for k in v.items() ]

dic_counts={k:wordlist.count(k) for k in keys}
dic={k1:{k2:dic_counts[k2] for k2 in v1.items()} for k1, v1 in dic.items()}
```

You don't need to ready keys as dict.

```py
dic_keys = {0:['year', 'drive', 'local' ],...}
wordlist = ['light', 'day', 'year', 'day', 'party', 'care', 'local']

keys=[k for v in dic.values() for k in v.items() ]

dic_counts={k:wordlist.count(k) for k in keys}
#dic={k1:{k2:dic_counts[k2] for k2 in v1.items()} for k1, v1 in dic.items()}
dic={k1:{k2:dic_counts[k2] for k2 in v1} for k1, v1 in dic.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more efficient solution that iterates only once on the list of names, and once on the nested dict, so it will be O(nb of items of dict + size of list):

```
from collections import Counter

dic = {0:{'year': 0, 'drive': 0, 'local': 0,},
       1:{'day': 0, 'element': 0, 'party': 0},
       2:{'carry': 0}}

wordlist = ['light', 'day', 'year', 'day', 'party', 'care', 'local']

word_counts = Counter(wordlist)

for subdict in dic.values():
    for key in subdict:
        if key in word_counts:
            subdict[key] += word_counts[key]
            
print(dic)
# {0: {'year': 1, 'drive': 0, 'local': 1}, 1: {'day': 2, 'element': 0, 'party': 1}, 2: {'carry': 0}}
```

(note that `key in word_counts` is an O(1) operation)